# Would you call a wall at the end of a corridor a 'back wall'?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> Nearing the end of the corridor, he saw a door at the back wall?

Would you call the wall at the end of a corridor a 'back wall'?

Comment: No. As you have already used _end_, you could say 'a door in the far wall'.

Comment: I understand why that might make sense; however, corridors/hallways don't have common shapes, so they don't really have fronts or backs. That means they don't have front or back walls either. As @KateBunting suggested, *far wall* works better.

Comment: I'd probably call the ***wall at the end*** of a corridor the ***end wall***. But there's no "right answer" here.